# Trying to get rake sunspot:solr:run to execute

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I am trying to get the gems sunspot_rails and sunspot_solr up and running.  I have all the most recent gems downloaded and implemented the patch suggestion from https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/issues/160 but I am still getting the error shown below.

It seems that some of the files are copied but its getting hung up somewhere.  Im on a Windows 7 system, 64-bit using rails version 3.2.6 and gem 'sunspot_rails' version 1.3.3 and gem 'sunspot_solr' version 1.3.3.  I have spent hours trying to figure this out, any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

```
$ rake sunspot:solr:run

java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)

Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)

Copying c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_solr-1.3.3/solr/solr/conf/admin-extra.html => C:/Users/Molly Struve/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/WaterCooler/solr/conf/admin-extra.html

Copying c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_solr-1.3.3/solr/solr/conf/elevate.xml => C:/Users/Molly Struve/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/WaterCooler/solr/conf/elevate.xml

Copying c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_solr-1.3.3/solr/solr/conf/mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt => C:/Users/Molly Struve/My Documents/AptanaStudio 3 Workspace/WaterCooler/solr/conf/mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt

Copying c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_solr-1.3.3/solr/solr/conf/protwords.txt => C:/Users/Molly Struve/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/WaterCooler/solr/conf/protwords.txt

Copying c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_solr-1.3.3/solr/solr/conf/schema.xml => C:/Users/Molly Struve/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/WaterCooler/solr/conf/schema.xml

Copying c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_solr-1.3.3/solr/solr/conf/scripts.conf => C:/Users/Molly Struve/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/WaterCooler/solr/conf/scripts.conf

Copying c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_solr-1.3.3/solr/solr/conf/solrconfig.xml => C:/Users/Molly Struve/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/WaterCooler/solr/conf/solrconfig.xml

Copying c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_solr-1.3.3/solr/solr/conf/spellings.txt => C:/Users/Molly Struve/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/WaterCooler/solr/conf/spellings.txt

Copying c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_solr-1.3.3/solr/solr/conf/stopwords.txt => C:/Users/Molly Struve/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/WaterCooler/solr/conf/stopwords.txt

Copying c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sunspot_solr-1.3.3/solr/solr/conf/synonyms.txt => C:/Users/Molly Struve/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/WaterCooler/solr/conf/synonyms.txt

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Struve/My\
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Struve.My\
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: Struve/My\.  Program will exit.`java version "1.6.0_24"
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when there is space in your source path. Move your code to a path like "C:/WaterCooler" and try.

Comment: I assumed this based on the fact that the program exits at the space after "My" BUT why is it that all the other files are copied and written successfully to a path with spaces and suddenly it decides to throw an error at the end?

Comment: I am not really sure. I ran into the same issue and got it fixed by removing the space in the path. But did not have time to dig deep into it. Probably will try to find the reason when time permits.